# Highcharts - No X Axis Crosshair

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts 5.0.14 line chart in which the x-axis crosshair will not display.  The y-axis works.

```
xAxis: { crosshair: true },
yAxis: { crosshair: true },
```

Both the x-axis and y-axis documentation show objects so that's what I started with.  When the x-axis wasn't working and I started Googling and found a JSFiddle with them as `true` rather than objects.  I tried that and x-axis still does not work.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.crosshair

The following JSFiddle is linked directly from Highcharts' documentation.  It shows `crosshair: true` for both x and y and it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/crosshair-both/

Inspecting the HTML I found a `<path>` element with `class="highcharts-crosshair highcharts-crosshair-category undefined"` - the "undefined" class caught my eye.

I appreciate your attention, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately theres not really much to go by in your question. It just doesn't work but no other code to dig into to find the problem. Everything you mention seems correct.

Comment: Yup! I second @HalvorStrand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working though I don't understand why the chart configuration resulted in the x-axis crosshair not appearing.

Before wanting to use crosshairs, when I first built the chart I was populating `xAxis['categories']`.  I soon changed some of the chart design and no longer needed 'categories'.  While making the changes, rather than delete the code to populate it with the previous data I set it to `null`.

Long story short, once I removed 'categories' altogether the x-axis crosshair appeared.

Strange considering the documentation at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair.color states (for 'color')...

> The color of the crosshair. Defaults to... rgba(204,214,235,0.25) for category axes, where the crosshair by default highlights the whole category.

I'm not sure what the last part, "where the crosshair by default...", means.  Regardless, crosshairs *and* categories must work is what the documentation reveals.

Comment: Could you provide us with an example with your code?